# How to update many-many-relation entities with stateless object in Entity-Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-5

I have made a code-first model with following entities

```
public abstract class Model
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Media : Model
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag : Model 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IList<Media> Media { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public DbSet<Media> Media { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(x => x.Media).WithMany(x => x.Tags).Map(x =>
    {
       x.ToTable("Tags_X_Media");
       x.MapLeftKey("TagId");
       x.MapRightKey("MediaId");
    });
   ....
 }
```

DataRepository with interface:

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
  T Update<T>(T model) where T : Model;
}

public class DataRepository : IDataRepository
{
  public T Update<T>(T model) where T : Model
  {
    return PerformAction((context) =>
    {
      context.Set<T>().Attach(model);
      context.Entry(model).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
      context.SaveChanges();
      return model;
    }
  }

    private T PerformAction<T>(Func<Context, T> toPerform) where T : Model
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
            context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return toPerform(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Save example:

```
//get uses .Include(x => x.Tags)
var media = DbRepository.Get<Media>(p => p.Id == "the id", x => x.Tags);

media.Tags.Add(new Tag { Name = "A tag name" });
DbRepository.Update<Media>(media);
```

Which is the proper way to add and remove entities in the cross-table Tags_X_Media as in save example above? If I set state to changed for instance Media.Tags this state is applied on tags-entity in dbo.Tags and I am not able to add a new row in the table. Is it possible to avoid a Tags_X_Media as a model in the code to make this work or is this that the only way to add or remove this entities?